# DNN How to get child portal url?

Tags: dotnetnuke

I manage to get the portal list from PortalController.GetPortals(). What is the next step for me to get the friendly URL from this list?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Take [this](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) tour to get to know how this site works and what it is for. Posting some code would be useful for the persons attempting to help you. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the FriendlyURL For a page in DotNetNuke you want to use

DotNetNuke.Common.Globals.NavigateURL()

If you want to get the Portal Alias for a portal, you can get that from the PortalSettings controller in DNN, that or simply look at the PortalAlias table based on the PortalID

Comment: I used to get the PortalAlias from PortalAliasController.GetPortalAliasByPortalID(PortalID), but this has return me with all the aliases. I am using DNN 7 with multilingual website, any idea how can I get the original alias (the one without the language code)?